# React Native: How do you find PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER using expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, auth0

I am trying to implement [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) on my react native app and right off the bat you need to identify your PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER for the callback the server uses through this template URL.

```
{PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}://{app_name}/ios/{PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}/callback
```

But since I'm using an [Expo project](https://expo.io/) I don't have the ios or android project folders. Am I missing something here or is it just impossible to configure an Auth0 with Expo created project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Auth0 React Native package uses native code; therefore, it's not compatible with Expo.

It looks like you may be able to work around this by using the web version instead, though. Expo has a [repo](https://github.com/expo/auth0-example) (possibly out of date) which demonstrates this.

Comment: It completely slipped my mind to look for a similar repo I found it and it looks like it could be promising showing the callback url upfront. I’ll mark you as answer. https://github.com/expo/auth0-example